# Algoritmo para sumar valores de cuentas hijas en cuentas padres en C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Lo que pasa es que tengo una lista con tres campos, los cuales son: `Cuenta`, `importe_A` e `importe_B`.

**Ejemplo de información:**

```
Cuenta = "1000.2.15.3"
Importe A = 230  
Importe B = 500  

Cuenta = "1000.2.15.4"  
Importe A = 100  
Importe B = 30  

Cuenta "1000.2.16.4"
Importe A = 160  
Importe B = 35
```

Lo que quiero hacer, es traer el importe de las cuentas según su nivel, y el nivel superior debe de traer la suma de las cuentas hijas.
Por ejemplo la cuenta `1000.2.15.4`  tiene cuatro niveles (donde el nivel `1` sería `1000`, el nivel `2` `2`, el `3` `15` y el `4` `4`) , cada nivel de la cuenta esta separado por `.`

Un ejemplo de datos de entrada/salida que pretendo son:

**Entrada**

> El importe_A de la cuenta 1000.2.15.4 es de 100
>
> El Importe_A de la cuenta 1000.2.15.3 es de 230
>
> El importe_A de la cuenta 1000.2.16.4 es de 160

**Salida**

> la suma del importe_A de la cuenta 1000.2.15 es de 330
>
> la suma del importe_A de la cuenta 1000.2.16 es de 160
>
> la suma del importe_A de la cuenta 1000.2 es de 490
>
> la suma del importe_A de la cuenta 1000 es de 490

Cada cuenta lleva la suma del importe según la cuenta padre coincida y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al ultimo padre, es decir hasta que la cuenta ya no tenga mas "."

Mi pregunta es, ¿habrá una manera de separar las cuentas por "." para obtener los padres, e ir sumando el importe de cada cuenta en su respectivo padre?

logre separar las cuentas con un split('.') pero no logro hacer la suma de sus importes en las cuentas padres.

Comment: ¿Como identificas a las cuentas padres y las hijas?

Comment: Es decir donde guardas las cuentas en variables, base de datos, etc.

Comment: Las cuentas padres las identifico segun el valor que está antes del punto, por ejemplo, la cuenta 1000.2.15.4 tiene 4 niveles, osea cada nivel se obtiene segun la separación por "." de la cuenta

Comment: toda la información de las cuentas e importes estan en una base de datos, con los campos antes mencionados

Comment: Hola Alfredo, no se entiende bien el problema, en tu lugar intentaría redactar la pregunta de otra manera, sino va a ser complicado que alguien pueda ayudarte

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, intentare redactarla mejor

Comment: Pues no veo problema con el split() lo divides por los puntos y eso te devuelve un arreglo y accedes a cualquier cuenta según su index en el arreglo.

Comment: eso si, el problema es que necesito sumar el importe de cada cuenta en su cuenta padre

Comment: @AlfredoJosueBoche tenes una clase con esas 3 propiedades, las usas en un `List<T>` y queres agrupar la suma según las cuentas padres?

Comment: si, exactamente @JuanSalvadorPortugal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes solucionar tu problema usando Linq y `GroupBy`.

Asumiendo que tu clase esta definida de la siguiente manera:

```
public class C
{
    public string Cuenta { get; set; }
    public int ImporteA { get; set; }
    public int ImporteB { get; set; }

    //Método que devuelve el string correspondiente a la cuenta padre
    //También podría definirse como Propiedad, y podría ser hasta mas sencillo
    public static string GetCuentaPadre(string grupo)
    {
        var Splitted = grupo.Split(".");
        return string.Join(".",Splitted.Take(Splitted.Count() - 1).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Luego, defino una `List<C>` con los datos que planteaste en el ejmplo

```
List<C> Lista = new List<C>
        {
            new C { Cuenta= "1000.2.15.3", ImporteA=230, ImporteB=500 },
            new C { Cuenta= "1000.2.15.4", ImporteA=100, ImporteB=30 },
            new C { Cuenta= "1000.2.16.4", ImporteA=160, ImporteB=35 }
        };
```

Luego, usando Linq y GroupBy obtengo una colección anónima

```
//Uso el primer select para crear un objeto anónimo que tenga la propiedad CuentaPadre
var Result = Lista.Select(r => new
    {
    CuentaPadre = C.GetCuentaPadre(r.Cuenta),
    r.ImporteA,
    r.ImporteB
    })
        //Agrupo por CuentaPadre (que fue definida arriba)
        .GroupBy(x => x.CuentaPadre)
        //Ahora si realizo el select del objeto final
        .Select(x => new
            {
            //x.Key representa la propiedad por la cual se realizó el group by
            CuentaPadre = x.Key,
            //Utilizo Sum para generar los importes
            ImporteA = x.Sum(d => d.ImporteA),
            ImporteB = x.Sum(d => d.ImporteB)
            });
```

Ahora `Result` es un `IEnumerable` de tipo anónimo que tiene la información que pretendías.

```
foreach(var resultado in Result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cuenta {0} , ImporteA {1}, ImporteB {2}",resultado.CuentaPadre,resultado.ImporteA,resultado.ImporteB);
        }
```

Esto generará como salida:

> ```
> Cuenta 1000.2.15 , ImporteA 330, ImporteB 530
> Cuenta 1000.2.16 , ImporteA 160, ImporteB 35
> ```

Te dejo un [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nNDfKa) con el ejemplo funcionando por cualquier duda.

Éxitos!