# LinQ - Extraer valor máximo entre 2 fechas

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, lambda

Tengo una lista de elementos, llamada `PeriodicoTerminal`, los cuales tienen un campo `FechaHora` que puede variar entre varios dias (por ejemplo del 02/10/18 12:00:00 al 05/10/18 12:00:00, con intervalos de 15 minutos). A su vez, hay otro campo llamado `VrmsM` que es un valor float (hace referencia al voltaje). Lo que yo necesito es crear un nuevo elemento con el máximo valor de `VrmsM` **en cada día**. Al final habría creado un elemento por cada día en el rango de fechas.

Hice algo así:

```
    while (FechaWhile <= FechaHastaSeleccionada)
         PeriodicoSeleccionado = (from p in PeriodicoTerminal
                         where p.VrmsM == PeriodicoTerminal.Max(x => x.VrmsM) && p.FechaHora.Date == FechaWhile.Date
                         select new PeriodicoTerminalDTO
                         {
                                VrmsM = p.VrmsM,
                                FechaHora = p.FechaHora
                         }).FirstOrDefault();
         FechaWhile = FechaWhile.AddDays(1);
    }
```

Pero no funciona. Me trae el valor maximo de toda la lista en general, cuando `FechaWhile` es la de ese registro máximo. En el resto de los casos retorna nulo.

Intenté también esto:

```
    while (FechaWhile <= FechaHastaSeleccionada)
         PeriodicoSeleccionado = (from p in PeriodicoTerminal
                         where p.FechaHora.Date == FechaWhile.Date
                         select new PeriodicoTerminalDTO
                         {
                                VrmsM = PeriodicoTerminal.Max(x => x.VrmsM),
                                FechaHora = p.FechaHora
                         }).FirstOrDefault();
         FechaWhile = FechaWhile.AddDays(1);
    }
```

Pero en este caso me trae siempre el valor mayor de toda la lista, sigue sin filtrarlo por dia.

Muchas gracias!

PD: Trabajo en C#.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo de tu planteo, lo único que necesitas es un `group by` podes dejar un ejemplo de datos de entrada y ejemplo de datos de salida? Agrega también la definición de las clases que intervienen!,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema puede solucionarse usando Linq y [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Para explicarlo de una manera más práctica, voy a usar una clase (asumo que similar a la de tu caso particular)

```
public class Ejemplo
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public float Voltaje { get; set; }
}
```

Ahora creo un `List<Ejemplo>` para llenar la lista de información para el ejemplo

```
    List<Ejemplo> PeriodicoTerminal = new List<Ejemplo>();
    PeriodicoTerminal.Add(new Ejemplo { Fecha = new DateTime(2018,12,12,13,00,00), Voltaje=100 });
    PeriodicoTerminal.Add(new Ejemplo { Fecha = new DateTime(2018,12,12,13,15,00), Voltaje=101 });
    PeriodicoTerminal.Add(new Ejemplo { Fecha = new DateTime(2018,12,12,13,30,00), Voltaje=40 });
    PeriodicoTerminal.Add(new Ejemplo { Fecha = new DateTime(2018,12,13,15,30,00), Voltaje=50 });
    PeriodicoTerminal.Add(new Ejemplo { Fecha = new DateTime(2018,12,13,13,30,00), Voltaje=40 });
    PeriodicoTerminal.Add(new Ejemplo { Fecha = new DateTime(2018,12,17,10,00,00), Voltaje=40 });
```

Teniendo ya los datos cargados, vamos a lo importante, agrupo la lista según la propiedad [Date](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.7.2), y luego uso [Enumerable.Max](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.7.2) para obtener el mayor voltaje en cada fecha

```
List<Ejemplo> Resultado = PeriodicoTerminal
    //Agrupo según la propiedad Date de Fecha
    .GroupBy(x => x.Fecha.Date)
    //El valor de Key aloja la fecha por la que agrupamos, y utilizamos x.Max para obtener 
    //el mayor voltaje dentro de la fecha
    .Select(x => new Ejemplo { Fecha = x.Key , Voltaje = x.Max(c => c.Voltaje) })
    .ToList();
```

Ahora, en `Resultado` ya tenemos la información que buscabamos

```
foreach(Ejemplo e in Resultado)
{
    Console.WriteLine("El día {0} el voltaje máximo fue {1}", e.Fecha.ToShortDateString(), e.Voltaje);
}
```

Lo que producirá la siguiente salida:

> ```
> El día 12/12/2018 el voltaje máximo fue 101
> El día 13/12/2018 el voltaje máximo fue 50
> El día 17/12/2018 el voltaje máximo fue 40
> ```

En caso de necesitar acotar el rango de fechas podrías perfectamente usar [Enumerable.Where](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2), te dejo un pequeño ejemplo

```
List<Ejemplo> Resultado = PeriodicoTerminal
    .Where(x => x.Fecha.Date > new DateTime(2018,12,12))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Fecha.Date)    
    .Select(x => new Ejemplo { Fecha = x.Key , Voltaje = x.Max(c => c.Voltaje) })
    .ToList();
```

En este caso, sólo evaluará fechas mayores al 12/12/2018.

Te dejo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/208106/77052), que trata un tema similar y quizás te sea de utilidad leerla

Saludos

Edit: dejo un pequeño [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9vCQJ3)

Comment: Wow! Sos un crack! Desde ya que marqué tu respuesta como aceptada, porque resuelve mi problema. Pero me olvidé de aclarar algo. Mis datos de Fecha, tienen tambien la hora, minutos y segundos. El filtro esta perfecto, yo solo necesito filtrar por dia. Pero el elemento de la nueva lista (en tu ejemplo "Resultado") debe guardarse con el valor completo del DateTime, es decir Fecha más hora, minutos y segundos. Es posible realizar esto? Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Podes hacer algo como esto `Select(x => new Ejemplo { Fecha = PeriodicoTerminal.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Voltaje==x.Max(v => v.Voltaje)).Fecha , Voltaje = x.Max(c => c.Voltaje) })`, pero **seguro** existe una mejor forma de hacerlo (en este caso, si el voltaje es el mismo en dos horarios distintos, sólo devolvería el primero)

Comment: No hay problema en que me traiga el primero, estaria bien. Pero por alguna razon no esta funcionando. Me trae valores totalmente aleatorios en cuanto a la fecha (de hecho varios corresponden al mismo dia y alñgunos dias ni siquiera figuran). Es como si se rompiera el group by.

Comment: Decime si de esta manera tenes el resultado que esperas `List<Ejemplo> Resultado = PeriodicoTerminal                
        .GroupBy(x => x.Fecha.Date)               
        .Select(x => new Ejemplo { Fecha = x.FirstOrDefault().Fecha , Voltaje = x.Max(c => c.Voltaje) })
        .ToList();`

Comment: En este caso me muestra solo la fecha, sin la hora, minutos y segundos (tal cual la primera respuesta que me diste). Y en el caso anterior, lo que pasa es que en el ultimo dia encuentra un valor X, y ese mismo valor tambien esta en el primer dia, entonces como utilizo el metodo FirstOrDefault(), me trae la primera fecha que encuentra.

Answer (score 2):

Basado en el ejemplo de Juan Salvador Portugal la seleccion puedes hacerla de esta forma:

```
List<Ejemplo> Resultado = PeriodicoTerminal
    .GroupBy(x => x.Fecha.Date)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(c => c.Voltaje).FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

O de esta:

```
List<Ejemplo> Resultado = PeriodicoTerminal
    .GroupBy(x => x.Fecha.Date)
    .Select((IGrouping<DateTime, Ejemplo> x) => {
        return x.OrderByDescending(c => c.Voltaje).FirstOrDefault();
    }).ToList();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/49sxoB

Comment: Esta muy buena tu solución, si podes, explica como funciona porfavor!

Comment: Eres increible amigo! Probe la segunda opcion (antes de que editaras) y funciona a la perfección. En breves pruebo la primera. Enormemente gracias a los 2!

Comment: El inconveniente de utilizar Max es que se pierde todo el objeto relacionado al valor maximo. En cambio si se utiliza un ordenamiento desendete y se obtiene el primer valor de la lista ordenada, entonces encontramos el objeto con el valor maximo de voltaje.

Comment: Ya que estamos te pregunto aca mismo. Ademas del máximo necesito calcular el minimo y el promedio. Para el caso del minimo es facil, o cambio el "OrderByDescending" por "OrderBy" o el "FirstOrDefault" por "LastOrDefault". Pero para el caso del promedio existe alguna variante parecida?

Comment: Estas en lo correcto, solo cambia el `OrderByDescending` por `OrderBy` y eso seria todo. Para el promedio cambia ya que si mal y no me equivoco se calcula sumando los valores y dividiendo entre la cantidad, si es asi, el inconveniente seria que una vez calculado el promedio de cual de todas las fecha es la que se asignara a ese promedio.

Comment: Al igual que los anteriores casos, necesito el promedio por dia. Si tengo los dias del 2 al 5, tendria 4 promedios, uno para cada dia. Y aqui no necesito fecha y hora, solo la fecha (el dia).

Comment: `List<Ejemplo> Resultado = PeriodicoTerminal
 .GroupBy(x => x.Fecha.Date)
 .Select((IGrouping<DateTime, Ejemplo> x) => {
  Ejemplo ejm = new Ejemplo();
  ejm.Fecha = x.Key;
  ejm.Voltaje = x.Sum(c => c.Voltaje) / x.Count();
  // tener presente la division por cero
  return ejm;
 }).ToList();`

Comment: Gracias, gracias y mas gracias!